# What does this C statement do?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Folks, my professor has assigned us an assignment involving typing with arrays, pointers, and functions. Now, before you jump on my back with the whole "We aren't going to do your homework for you" thing, the answer to my question will not solve the problem. In fact, I've already taken my best guess at the answer. I am just curious to hear what you think about this.

Here is the C statement I was given:

```
double(*foo(double(*)(double,double[]),double))(double, ...);
```

Our problem involved describing the type of foo. My question is simply this: What on earth does this statement do? As far as I can read it, this is either one of the most obfuscated and unrealistic lines of code I've ever seen, or it's not actually valid C. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Something horrible, that's what it declares. Plug it into cdecl.org to get the idea of what it means (you will probably have to remove the `...` as cdecl hates them.

Comment: Your professor is obviously a sadist.

Comment: @ruslik, variadic is the least problematic part of this statement. :p

Comment: @birryree for me, but not for cdecl.org

Comment: It's not a statement at all, it's a declaration.

Comment: What this statement do is giving you "no hire" on interview and severe pay cut if found in production code. May be professor will like this answer? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want to learn is the [Clockwise Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). Learning this will help you describe, in plain words, what any type in C is. Learn it well.

Comment: @GMan, the type is what this _student_ will come up with by applying the education that jer has just given. "Teach a man to fish" and all that jazz. +1 for educating rather than just handing over answers.

Comment: @pax: About about teach him to fish and give him a fish while you're at it, showing him how to apply his newly found fishing skills step-by-step?

Comment: @jer: Definite +1 for being clear, educating (me as well as the asker of this question).  :)

Answer (score 0):

This will help a little

```
typedef RETURNTYPE (* POINTER_TO_FUNCTION_TYPE)(ARGTYPE1, ARGTYPE2)
```

C supports a type that is a pointer to function, and you can typedef one this way to simplify longer expressions based on it.

So, with this typedef, I could declare this function

```
POINTER_TO_FUNCTION_TYPE f(POINTER_TO_FUNCTION_TYPE g);
```

It's a function that takes a pointer to function and returns a pointer to a function.  Without the typedef, imagine how that declaration would look.

Answer (score 0):

According to my compiler (Visual Studio 2010) **the statement does absolutely nothing**. It compiles successfully, but there are no assembly instructions generated for it, so the debugger steps right over it. As for *why* it does nothing and what it really means - it would take someone with more knowledge of C than me to explain that.

I can figure out the type of `foo` using the clockwise/spiral rule, though - thanks, **jer**! It's easier if you reformat it a bit:

```
double
(
    *foo
    (
        double(*)(double, double[]),
        double
    )
)
(double, ...);
```

Comment: Yeah, I got that alright on my own. I was just wondering what the heck it does. At this point, I figure you need to add a function body somewhere in order to make it actually recognized by the compiler, since it is meant to point to a function.

Comment: It doesn't generate any code because it's a type declaration.